# How can I create a circle feature that will have a constant radius in pixels even on zoom in and zoom out?

Tags: openlayers, distance, pixel

Creating SVG icons have also solve it with much greater flexibility:

```
var svgXmlCircle = '<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ' +
        'xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="55" height="55" ' +
        ' xml:space="preserve">'+
        '<circle fill="#FF0000" cx="27.5" cy="14" r="14" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"/>' +
        '</svg>';

    var svgIcon = new Image();
    svgIcon.src = 'data:image/svg+xml,' + escape(svgXmlCircle);

    return [
        new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                img: svgIcon, // for new implem
                imgSize:[55,55], // for new implem
            }))
        }),
        new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Icon(({
                src: 'images/map-' + itemType + '.svg',
                scale: .1,
                //center bottom of the marker
                anchor: [0.5, 1],
                anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                anchorYUnits: 'fraction',
                opacity: 1
            }))
        })
    ];
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: none yet. I am thinking of using a style function that computes the radius based on pixel to actual distance but no luck yet on how to do it.

Comment: Since this is a **volunteer** site, it is **highly recommended** that you actually **try something first**.  Show some effort and people will be more likely to help you out.  That being said, you can probably take your map width to generate a distance/pixel ratio based off scale as zoom changes.  Then it is a matter of finding your center point and creating your circle every time.

Comment: Hi @Branco added my own solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it as a point with fixed radius, it will create a circle of given radius and will have constant radius even on zoom

```
var circlestyle = new ol.style.Style({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([parseFloat(lon), parseFloat(lat)], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857')),
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 7,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: 'orange'
      })
    }),
});
```